# Limit $\lim_{x \to \infty}x^e/e^x$

Tags: calculus, limits

I had this problem on my math test, and was stuck on it for quite some time.

$\lim_{x \to \infty}x^e/e^x$

I knew that the bottom grew faster than the top, but I didn't know how to prove it. I wrote that the limit approaches 0, but I am not sure how to prove it mathematically.

Comment: From the Taylor series, $$e^x \ge \frac{x^4}{4!}.$$

Comment: Have you learnt L'Hospital's rule?

Comment: @MonkeyKing yes, I kept getting infinty over infinty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show first that it is in indeterminate form.

Then perform L'Hopital's rule, differentiating the top and bottom.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^e}{e^x}= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ex^{e-1}}{e^x}=e(e-1)(e-2)\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x^{3-e}e^x}=0$$

Comment: I did that and kept getting infinity over infinity

Comment: @SergeiLevashov From the moment the exponent in the numerator becomes less than one, it's time to stop...

Answer (score 1):

If $x>0$ then $e^x>\frac{x^3}{6}$, by the power series for $e^x$.

So $\frac{x^e}{e^x}<\frac{6}{x^{3-e}}\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$.